# Prompt "server" PC to run python file

Tags: python, latex

We have developed code to compile calculations into tex files and then convert to pdf's. We are now trying to instead of generating the pdf on local PC's to simply send the tex file to a hosting PC and prompting this PC to run a python file (using its own Python.exe instance) that will then generate the PDF and send to a server folder.

It might seem like a silly approach (since it can be generated on the local PC) but we are trying to remove the step where people have to install software like MikTex and Strawberry on local PC's completely and not use an online converter like Overleaf.

Is there a way that this is possible?

Comment: What you describe is a server that runs a Python code in response to some input. There are many ways to do this, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Yes exactly this would be perfect - you mentioned a few approaches. Which would you recommend?

Comment: I can't recommend any -except learning about (web) servers- because I don't know your requirements. However, if you're familiar with Python, you may want to check out Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/). Besides, asking for software recommendations is off-topic on SO.